# Does codesign sign apps recursively by default?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcodebuild, codesign

I am doing some build-script archaeology and we have a fairly complex build in which we remove code signatures using `codesign --remove` so we can remove architectures using `lipo`.

In the end the app is signed like this (I see it in the log):

```
codesign --force -s DeveloperIDCertificate --keychain pathToKeychain YourApp.app
```

My question is: Is this a recursive operation? We are *not* using `--deep`, but perhaps it's deep by default when signing the whole `.app`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recursive.
And documentation says to avoid using `--deep` and that it is better to iterate through the files yourself.

See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128166 under the `Sign Your Code` section.